# html- input tag drop down not showing for previous entered values

Tags: html

My input tag in a form is not showing the suggestions for previous entered values

```
<form target="temp" method="post" action="">
                    <input id="UserID" name="UserID" type="text" placeholder="User ID" autocomplete="on" spellcheck="false">
                    <input id="Password" type="password" placeholder="Password" spellcheck="false">
                    <input type="button" value='Submit' onclick="login();">
</form>
```

What is happening is:

[image]

I want it to be:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make most browsers display values previously entered in `input` fields by giving a `name` to the `input`.

Change first `input` to this:

```
<input id="UserID" name="UserID" type="text" placeholder="User ID" spellcheck="false">
```

**UPDATE**

Not sure what your `onClick` function is doing but...

Change `type="button"` to `type="submit"`:

```
<input type="submit" value='Submit' />
```

Comment: Updated answer for you

Comment: I dont want to submit the form and i'm using javascript instead of sending the form to a php file, so I made the type as button

Comment: If it doesn't submit, it won't save the value

Comment: Is there any way to make it working for type button?

Comment: Not that I know of... basically, if the values are not posted... it won't save them. If you don't want to submit the form... why even use `method="post"`?